# Java HashMap cannot find key from within ListDataListener event

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashcode

Can someone explain why the HashMap acts like it does in this example:
Simple test that checks a hashmap for a key. Once in the constructor and once in ListDataListener intervallAdded method.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.event.ListDataEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;

import com.jgoodies.common.collect.ArrayListModel;

public class Test1 {

  private final Listener listener = new Listener();
  private final Map<List<?>, Object> parentByCollection = new HashMap<List<?>, Object>();

  public Test1(){
    ArrayListModel<Object> list = new ArrayListModel<Object>();

    list.addListDataListener(listener);

    parentByCollection.put(list, new Integer(10));

    // Test containsKey locally
    System.out.println("Item exists (locally):" + parentByCollection.containsKey(list));

    // Test containsKey via ListDataListener
    list.add(new Integer(20));
  }

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test1();
  }

  public class Listener implements ListDataListener{

    @Override
    public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
      List<?> itemSource = (List<?>)e.getSource();

      System.out.println("Item exists (listener):" + parentByCollection.containsKey(itemSource));      
    }

    @Override
    public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Why does the hashmap return false from the event but true from constructor when using containsKey?
Is there some java-generics "magic" I don't know about here?

Edit:

Just found that ArrayList's (which ArrayListModel extends) hashCode method assembles its hashcode from all its elements. Which means the hashCode changes with the items in the list.
So storing a ArrayList in a HashMap is not a good idea.

How can I solve this? Store the collections in a holder/container object instead?

Comment: Please provide hashCode() method implementation for `com.jgoodies.common.collect.ArrayListModel`.

Comment: You can find sources here http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html  ArrayListModel extends ArrayList and doesn't override hashCode so I guess the ArrayList's hashCode is the one that is used.   But I can't see how that is relevant, the first call to containsKey returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you understand the problem now, but here is the explanation for other people:

The HashMap uses the hashcode of the key, which in this case is the hashcode of the List.

Looking at the javadoc of the hashcode method of List explains that the hashcode of the list depends on the contained elements in order to respect the contract between hashcode and equality.

Due to the contract any subsequent modification of the list resulting in an equality change will also result in a hashcode change and thus the Hashmap will not be able to retrieve the initial list.

The solution in this case is to use a reference, it will not change when elements are added or removed from the list. But a clone of the list (one that is equal to it) will not work !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite obvious when I looked through the sources. The solution to store collections in a map is to NOT use HashMap but instead using a map based on references like apache commons ReferenceIdentityMap or java.util.IdentityHashMap.

Comment: or reimplement hashCode method.

Comment: Sure thats a solution too. But it's a much more cleaner solution to use a Map that works with reference-equality for keys.

Comment: Mush more cleaner solution is to not use Lists as keys for map)

Comment: @Stas: If not using list as key, how can I find a "matching" object inside the intervallAdded event? All i have there is e.getSource()